# shell script missing [: missing ]

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement

I've been looking for a moment to my code but I can't find any error ..
The error I get is this one:

```
./dotest.sh: 79: [: missing ]
./dotest.sh: 89: [: missing ]
```

This is my script, the problem is in the two ifs listed below, knowing that others similar if statement are assumed to be correct when being executed.

```
#### FIRST LINE OF ERROR
if [ "$view" -eq 1 ] ; then
    # bien sur: eliminer les doublons et les lignes Please ... 
    nb_mots_trouves=$(./words < req.txt | egrep -v "Please enter some letters" | sort | uniq | wc -l)
    echo " $nb_mots_trouves ont été trouvés au total: "
    echo " " 
    ./words < req.txt | egrep -v "Please enter some letters" | sort | uniq

# pas d'option view
else
    #### SECOND LINE OF ERROR
    if ! [ -x "mots_aleatoires" ] ; then
        gnatmake mots_aleatoires.adb
    fi
    ./mots_aleatoires "$nb_cars" "$nb_mots"

    timetest="time-$stdOutput"
    # ici on cree un deuxieme fichier texte contenant le resultat du time
    # on le concatenera ensuite a la sortie choisie
    (time ./words < req.txt | egrep -v "Please enter some letters" | sort | uniq > "$stdOutput") 2> "$timetest"

fi
```

I really thank you in advance, your help can save me a lot of time .

Comment: coudln't find anything wrong with the provided lines using [`shellcheck`](http://www.shellcheck.net/), you may need to provide more of your script for the problem to show

Comment: The whole script is 100 lines long .. I don't think it's a good idea, I will however paste the if block

Comment: there doesnt seem to be anything wrong with this if block, I suspect you are missing a closing `"` or `'` above the block

Comment: That was my impression as well. Fortunately I'm not wrong (in thinking that) .. that's weird however! :'(

Comment: May be printing contents of `$view` would give you some hint?

Comment: @Marrakchino You could run your script through spellcheck.net, though, without pasting it here.

Comment: Thank you all. I finally decided to remove these blocs to the detriment of a more clear and complete script.

Comment: You understand that the 79 in `./dotest.sh: 79: ...` is line # 79 of your code? When you turn on line numbering, do you have an `[` char on line 79? If not the error is most likely between lines 1-78 ;-) . If http://shellcheck.net doesn't find your problem (as recommended above), you may need to comment out various logic blocks of the code, NOTE if the error line number report changes, and try to track it down that way. Good luck.

Comment: The error means that bash can't find the closing parenthese. This would be the case if you don't have a space in front of it. Now it looks like you *do* have a space, so you should not get this error. Maybe you have some strange character in the code, which is not a space, but when looking at it by the editor displays like a space. Maybe you should look at your `if` statements with a hex editor....